# Iptables - facing problems to allow specific ports and block others

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I tried to block all ports except 22(ssh), 80(http), 443(https). My current INPUT rules are these.

```
> iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

it should accept http and https port and then block everything else. but It's blocking everything. for example when I try to visit facebook which uses port 80 & 443, it doesn't work. I can't visit facebook. what should I do now?

I also tried like this. Allowed mentioned ports and made the *policy DROP*, though I'm not sure. the same happens.

```
> iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:ssh
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:https
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:http
```

Comment: You are using Kali Linux?

Comment: yes. @NasirRiley i know there's no need to mention it

Comment: Kali Linux is not for beginners. It is meant for penetration testing and it's designed with the idea that the user will have a good base knowledge of Linux at the very least. Even if you are using it for that, I would recommend that you use a distro such as Ubuntu first to get more familiar with it before using Kali Linux.

Comment: Secondly, you don't need ports 80 and 443 open to access other websites. The iptables rules that you have are for allowing access to your machine if you are running a webserver and hosting websites.

Comment: In your case, you want to test your network connectivity. Try pinging other addresses in your local network. Also, can you post the output of the following commands: `ifconfig` `cat /etc/network/interfaces` `cat /etc/resolv.conf`  `service network-manager status`

Comment: what will happen if use kali as newbie? I'm not completely new. I used linux before. I don't like multiple os in same pc. I'm pretty comfortable with kali. I can do everything I need to do. plus I'm learning Ethical Hacking. if we exclude the matter of uses, what wrong will happen to me for using kali?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The policy rules that you've created will allow *outside* hosts to connect to *your* TCP ports 22, 80 and 443, but not allow any other traffic, including your own! If you really want to prevent this host from accessing anything other than these three ports, and don't want outside hosts to access yours *at all*, you can put the rules on your `OUTPUT` rule chain instead of your `INPUT` one and then have a CONNTRACK rule on your input chain to prevent connections that you didn't initiate:

```
-P INPUT DROP
-P OUTPUT DROP
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -m udp -p udp --sport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m udp -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

I usually allow the loopback adapter to work normally as some internal programs may need it; as well, I would allow DNS traffic, or else you won't be able to resolve domain names.

Comment: it resolved just by adding related and established. but I didn't got the point why I should add these output rules. could you please explain a little more?

Comment: Well-known port numbers apply to the server, not the client, so if you want to allow access to only certain ports on other hosts, you need to check on data being *sent*, not received. In this case, you indicated that you only wanted programs to be able to access HTTP(S) and SSH ports (and DNS), so those are what I put in the `OUTPUT` section; everything else will be dropped.

Answer (score 1):

As others pointed out in the comments, you do not need INPUT rules like those to access websites. You would only need these rules if you were running services on these ports locally. If you did want to restrict outbound traffic instead, these rules would need to go in the OUTPUT chain.

Additionally, you are losing all connectivity because you are DROPping all inbound traffic. When you make a connection to a webserver, the returning data (specifically, the TCP 3 way handshake) will be DROPPed in the INPUT chain because of your catch-all drop. To fix this, you need to add a rule to allow these return connections:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `update-alternatives --config iptables` and select the legacy version.
Worked for me for the time being.

Comment: I've edited your answer to add code formatting, remove signature and replace dash character with `--`. However, to be a good answer, it could do with more detail, explaining what this command does. See [answer].

Comment: I just needed to allow established connections. I noticed, like others said, your web server uses multiple random ports other than http or ssh after the connection is established. So I just needed that. It's a little more complicated while setting up a firewall.